Migration of cloud instanced hosted containerized application with stored data to a difference cloud vendor
If we have an application running on physical disk with MBR partition for example, application is ITSM application. The application uses micro-services i.e., individual docker containers for individual component for example, dbms, api, dashboard-ui.
The application data is getting overloaded and now we need to migrate the whole application including its stored data to a virtual disk to a cloud vendor.
The application uses kafka, cassandra and elasticsearch kind of functionalities + own tech also.
